# Troubles with Codeigniter's Native Session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using Codeigniter's Native Session Class for storing users information, but i have a serious problem. It appears that the session times out when the user is inactive for about half an hour and logs him out.

My config file looks like this:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 60*60*24*30*12*2;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE; 
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 7200;
```

The PHPSESSID in browser is not destroyed when the user is logged out and it expires in two years as I've set it in config file.

I don't know what are the common problems with native session class because everyone seems to be happy with it, so can somebody work it out what is the most likely thing that is causing this problem?

Edit: For those who aren't familiar with codeigniter's native session class here is link
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session

Answer (score 0):

i use also codeigniter's native class. Maybe you not config it correctly. Here is code that i get from him. https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');



    class CI_Session {

    var $session_id_ttl; // session id time to live (TTL) in seconds
    var $flash_key = 'flash'; // prefix for "flash" variables (eg. flash:new:message)

    function __construct()
    {
        log_message('debug', "Native_session Class Initialized");
        $this->object =& get_instance(); 
        $this->_sess_run();
    }

    /**
    * Regenerates session id
    */
    function regenerate_id()
    {
        // copy old session data, including its id
        $old_session_id = session_id();
        $old_session_data = $_SESSION;

        // regenerate session id and store it
        session_regenerate_id();
        $new_session_id = session_id();

        // switch to the old session and destroy its storage
        session_id($old_session_id);
        session_destroy();

        // switch back to the new session id and send the cookie
        session_id($new_session_id);
        session_start();

        // restore the old session data into the new session
        $_SESSION = $old_session_data;

        // update the session creation time
        $_SESSION['regenerated'] = time();

        // session_write_close() patch based on this thread
        // http://www.codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/1624/
        // there is a question mark ?? as to side affects

        // end the current session and store session data.
        session_write_close();
    }

    /**
    * Destroys the session and erases session storage
    */
    function destroy()
    {
        unset($_SESSION);
        if ( isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] ) )
        {
              setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
        }
        session_destroy();
    }

    /**
    * Reads given session attribute value
    */    
    function userdata($item)
    {
        if($item == 'session_id'){ //added for backward-compatibility
            return session_id();
        }else{
            return ( ! isset($_SESSION[$item])) ? false : $_SESSION[$item];
        }
    }

    /**
    * Sets session attributes to the given values
    */
    function set_userdata($newdata = array(), $newval = '')
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => $newval);
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Erases given session attributes
    */
    function unset_userdata($newdata = array())
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => '');
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            }
        }        
    }

    /**
    * Starts up the session system for current request
    */
    function _sess_run()
    {
        session_start();

        $session_id_ttl = $this->object->config->item('sess_expiration');

        if (is_numeric($session_id_ttl))
        {
            if ($session_id_ttl > 0)
            {
                $this->session_id_ttl = $this->object->config->item('sess_expiration');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session_id_ttl = (60*60*24*365*2);
            }
        }

        // check if session id needs regeneration
        if ( $this->_session_id_expired() )
        {
            // regenerate session id (session data stays the
            // same, but old session storage is destroyed)
            $this->regenerate_id();
        }

        // delete old flashdata (from last request)
        $this->_flashdata_sweep();

        // mark all new flashdata as old (data will be deleted before next request)
        $this->_flashdata_mark();
    }

    /**
    * Checks if session has expired
    */
    function _session_id_expired()
    {
        if ( !isset( $_SESSION['regenerated'] ) )
        {
            $_SESSION['regenerated'] = time();
            return false;
        }

        $expiry_time = time() - $this->session_id_ttl;

        if ( $_SESSION['regenerated'] <=  $expiry_time )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
    * Sets "flash" data which will be available only in next request (then it will
    * be deleted from session). You can use it to implement "Save succeeded" messages
    * after redirect.
    */
    function set_flashdata($key, $value)
    {
        $flash_key = $this->flash_key.':new:'.$key;
        $this->set_userdata($flash_key, $value);
    }

    /**
    * Keeps existing "flash" data available to next request.
    */
    function keep_flashdata($key)
    {
        $old_flash_key = $this->flash_key.':old:'.$key;
        $value = $this->userdata($old_flash_key);

        $new_flash_key = $this->flash_key.':new:'.$key;
        $this->set_userdata($new_flash_key, $value);
    }

    /**
    * Returns "flash" data for the given key.
    */
    function flashdata($key)
    {
        $flash_key = $this->flash_key.':old:'.$key;
        return $this->userdata($flash_key);
    }

    /**
    * PRIVATE: Internal method - marks "flash" session attributes as 'old'
    */
    function _flashdata_mark()
    {
        foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value)
        {
            $parts = explode(':new:', $name);
            if (is_array($parts) && count($parts) == 2)
            {
                $new_name = $this->flash_key.':old:'.$parts[1];
                $this->set_userdata($new_name, $value);
                $this->unset_userdata($name);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * PRIVATE: Internal method - removes "flash" session marked as 'old'
    */
    function _flashdata_sweep()
    {
        foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value)
        {
            $parts = explode(':old:', $name);
            if (is_array($parts) && count($parts) == 2 && $parts[0] == $this->flash_key)
            {
                $this->unset_userdata($name);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

PHPs sessions expires after 1440 seconds (24 minutes).

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: CodeIgniter doesn't use PHP sessions. It has a custom cookie-based implementation instead.

Comment: @Gurrewe Yeah I know that but the line in config file $config['sess_expiration'] = 60*60*24*30*12*2; should overwrite that rule and set it that the session expires in two years.

Comment: @Narf I don't use codeigniter's default session class, but instead i've autoloaded native session that behaves similar to php session and doesn't use cookies for storing informations

Comment: @Mad_Eye Well ... those configuration variables are intended for CodeIgniter's session library. Unless you show the class that you're using - we can't even guess what the issue is.